# I want to hide woocommerce products from the shop loop which the user already puchased

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to hide those products from the shop loop which user already purchased

Answer (score 2):

hey you  can use  this to hide or remove  the product from the shop that is already purchased

```
   add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'user_logged_in_product_already_bought', 30 );

function user_logged_in_product_already_bought() {
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        global $product;
        $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
        if ( wc_customer_bought_product( $current_user->user_email, $current_user->ID, $product->get_id() ) ) 

        ?>
            <script>
                var productId = '<?= $product->get_id();  ?>';
                jQuery(document).ready(function(){
                   jQuery(".products li .post-"+productId).remove(); 
                });
            </script>
        <?php


    }
}
```

Comment: @ yoGesh did this fix your problem or not

Comment: Good idea - But you could manipulate the loop itself, to see if it is already bought, instead of waiting for everything to be loaded before removing it again - that way you could potentially save load times - and it would work without js

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use the below **wc_customer_bought_product** function to set the condition for your requirement.

First You have to refer below function code.

https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/function-wc_customer_bought_product.html